# What is a proper response to a joke about visiting dentist at 2:30/tooth hurty?

Tags: popular-refrains, jokes

I advised my client that I would be unavailable on a particular day because I have an appointment with the dentist to remove a tooth. The client responded

> What time is the appointment? 2:30?

The second before I wrote correct time of my appointment, I realized, that this might be a joke :)

How should I respond, if I want to be funny? Is there another "language joke" I can use in the reply?

Comment: The usual term is tooth-extraction.

Comment: Some versions involve time of appointment with "Chinese Dentist" ... "tooth-hurty"

Comment: You could say "Tooth hurty? Tusk, tusk!" or "Tooth hurty? Fangs a lot!"

Comment: "Yes, I tried asking for a different time but the dentist just brushed me off"

Comment: "That joke deserves an award! I'd give you a little plaque, but the dentist took mine away."

Comment: this does not age well, it's a racist joke

Comment: This is one of my favorite little jokes. I schedule my routine dental appointments (like the one I had today) for 2:30pm for exactly this reason. My hygienist loves it but she said in 40 years only me & my evil twin (yes, I have one) scheduled their appointments at 2:30 for this reason. It is absolutely NOT racist - it is a purely English language joke.

Answer (score 4):

A: What time is the appointment? 2:30?

B: Yes. 2:30. With Dr. Pullem at Yankem, Pullem, and Ouchi, PLC.

Answer (score -1):

As to the joke to use in the reply, if you don't like

> The most feared six words in the English language: "The dentist will see you now."

There is some number of other choices [here](http://www.jokes4us.com/peoplejokes/dentistjokes/dentistonelinersjokes.html)